# How can I override methods in Java when I create an Object via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, overriding

In *Java*, is it possible to override methods in a class that you create using `reflection`? For example, say I have the following class:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public String foo, bar;

    public MyObject(String foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = foo + "bar";
    }

    public void setBar(String bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

And in one class I want to create it directly and override its `setBar` method as follows:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject("something")
{
    @Override
    public void setBar(String bar)
    {
        this.bar = this.foo;
    }
};
```

Is there a way to override a method in this same manner using reflection? Maybe something like this? :

```
Class<?> _class = Class.forName("com.example.MyObject");
Constructor<?> _constructor = _class.getConstructor(new Class<?>[]{String.class});
Method m = _class.getMethod("setBar", new Class<?>[]{String.class});
Object obj = _constructor.newInstance("Foo String")
{
    m = new Method(new Class<?>[]{String.class})
    {
        System.out.println("Foobar");
    }
};
```

If not, are there other ways of doing this, or an external library that could help? I am looking for way to add listeners to a setter method in order to change binded values.

Comment: You need a dynamic code generation library, such as *javassist*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it's not possible in the way of your example.

In your example, the Java compiler will create two separate classes:

```
MyObject.class
MyObject$1.class
```

The latter being the one with the overridden method. In this case, it's an *anonymous inner class* (See [Java tutorial documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html))

But there is more complex solution involving bytecode weaving libraries. Libraries such as cglib, asm, javassist etc. give you a facility to dynamically create new classes at runtime and load them.

Javassist has a tutorial on how to [add methods to classes at runtime](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#add). It should be possible to adapt it to add/override the method, something like this:

```
CtClass origClazz = ClassPool.getDefault().get("org.example.MyObject");
CtClass subClass = ClassPool.getDefault().makeClass(cls.getName() + "New", origClazz);
CtMethod m = CtNewMethod.make(
             "public void setBar(String bar) { this.bar = bar; }",
             subClass );
subClass .addMethod(m);
Class clazz = cc.toClass();
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for - but I can definitely fit it in. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone try to do this with Mock?

Answer (score 2):

If you're returning an object of an interface type, you can use [`Proxy.newProxyInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html?is-external=true#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29) to get an instance of an interface that dynamically sends method invocations to an [`InvocationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) object which you can write to do whatever custom behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are asking for is something like runtime compilation. While not impossible it certainly isn't something that the reflection API provides.